# How to plot average in y axis for each x value in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using  matplotlib.pyplot to visualize my data. In pandas I have columns 'hour' and `'favourite_count'`. hour has values form 0 to 24. `favourite_count` is a continuous variable. What I want is to plot a bar chart which visualizes the average `favourite_count` for each hour. Currently I am plotting a basic graph as below. In the y axis this plots the sum / maximum of `favourite_count` for each hour (I am not sure which). How can I plot a graph that visualizes hour vs `average_favorite_count_for_hour`

```
plt.bar(result['hour'], result['favourite_count'])
plt.xlabel('hour')
plt.ylabel('favourite_count')
plt.title('hour vs popularity', y=1.1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use groupby command and then plot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform an averaging step by adding this line just before plotting:

```
result = result.groupby('hour').mean()
```

then plot as below:

```
plt.bar(result.index, result['favourite_count'])
plt.xlabel('hour')
plt.ylabel('favourite_count')
plt.title('hour vs popularity', y=1.1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

**Note the x axis is now the index.**